# Figuring out location of ImageView in a 2D array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to find the location of a specific imageView given an ID in a 2D array? For example if I have ImageView [x][y] and each of the ImageViews has an ID, is it possible to find the specific [x][y] of an Image given that I know the ID of the ImageView I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to iterate through and testing each ImageView using [getId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29).

If performance is a problem then you could build an index using HashMap with keys as ids and values as `(x, y)` pairs.

Comment: note that getId() will give you the ImageView's id and not the drawable id (if any) of the ImageView's bitmap.